# Ansible tags do not seem to work with roles

Tags: ansible, tags, roles

I am attempting to use tags to control if a task in a role is executed or not. As far as I can tell I have followed everything correctly, but the passed in tag is ignored. I have reduced the problem down to two files

**site.yml**

```yaml
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
          - { role: apache2, tags: ['install'] }
          - { role: apache2, tags: ['noinstall'] }
```

**roles/apache2/tasks/main.yml**

```yaml
- name: Run a task
  debug:
    msg: Hello

- name: Run a tagged task
  debug:
    msg: Hello again
  tags:
    - install
    #- never
```

My expectation is that the "Run a tagged task" should only be seen once. In the current setup it is run twice. If I remove the comment then the task is never seen. Neither of these results is correct.

Why are my tags not working? I'm using ansible version 2.9.6 on Ubuntu 20

Comment: There is a misconception from your side here, you believe that adding a tag on a role would limit the tasks of that role to the one matching this tag. But, adding tags at the role level applies this tags to all the tasks in the role, it does not limit the role to a tag, limiting based on tag can only be done at the command line level.

Comment: _[There are three ways to add tags to roles: 1. Add the same tag or tags to all tasks in the role by setting tags under `roles`.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-roles)_

Answer (score 0):

if we use `include_tasks` in a role --> then we have troubles with tags.
if we use `import_tasks` in a role --> all is ok

example:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.7]
```

a playbook: **admins.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: admins}
```

a role:
./roles/admins/tasks/**main.yml**

```
---


- name:  ' create | Debian ' 
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks:  "Debian/create.yml"
```

/roles/admins/tasks/Debian/**create.yml**

```
---

- name: tag2
  debug:
     msg: "tag2"
  tags: tag2


- name: tag3
  debug:
     msg: "tag3"
  tags: tag3
```

lets list tags:

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  --list-tags

playbook: admins.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: []
```

So we have troubles with tags.
Lets test it.

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  -t "tag3"

PLAY [localhost] 
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
ok: [localhost]
```

So zero tasks is accomplished.

lets change **main.yml**

```
---


- name:  ' create | Debian ' 
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks:  "Debian/create.yml"
```

Now we dont have troubles with tags:

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  --list-tags
playbook: admins.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [tag2, tag3]
```

Lets test it.

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  -t "tag3"

PLAY [localhost] 
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [admins : tag3] ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "tag3"
}
```